can i put cardamom pods in hand-grinder with the coffee beans?
As you may know, some coffees from the Middle-East / Mediterranean have cardamom ground into the coffee, which is super-fine and prepared in a copper/metal pot.
Is it safe for me to experiment with whole cardamom pods put inside hand-grinders like the Kingrinder K6?
Would it clog up the grinder because these pods contain more moisture and fibrous material?

Plenty of people say they grind spices in a coffee grinder without issue. A coffee site writer even says they grind parmesan - wild. If you do, you might consider putting some rice through the grinder afterward, to pull out some of the oils and residue.
That said, I wouldn’t recommend it with any reasonably expensive grinder - like the one you named. It feels like using a race car to tow a trailer - it may work, but it’s just not the tool for the job. And from a quality stance, the best grind size for the cardamom is likely different from the coffee.
The right tool is a molcajete or a mortar and pestle. They’re fast, affordable, easy to clean, don’t risk cross contamination, and allow easy experimenting with grind size.
(Edit: Will update with sources when able)

The burrs in my Ascaso burr grinder are carbide, hard enough to chew nails. Really. Carbide is used to machine hardened tool steel. I run cinnamon sticks through the Ascaso as well as coffee beans.
I can't think of any biological material that would match carbide for hardness, even tooth enamel. Diamond has a hardness rating of 10 on the Mohs scale, carbide 9.5

I think it should be ok to put cardamom pods inside the coffee grinder. I don't have a hand grinder but I've done it successfully with electric blade grinders.

Can you elaborate please: do you think the grinder type (burr vs. blade) matters here? My gut feeling agrees with your „it should be ok“, but I am wondering whether the setup matters, e.g a different behavior between coffee beans and cardamom pods in a burr grinder?

@Stephie I'm also feeling like maybe a burr grinder might not handle the full cardamom pod. What if you just do the seeds?
